# Django: How do I return JWT with custom claim after user Sign Up?

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I know how to create custom claims with `simplejwt`. Now I want to return custom claim in the tokens containing email after user signs up. How do I do this?

My serializer:

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, required=True, write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True, required=True)
    tokens = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_tokens(self, user):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token),
        }
    
    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password'] != data['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "Password fields didn't match."})
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        password2 = validated_data.pop('password2', None)
        
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)

        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'password', 'password2', 'tokens')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

It returns the default JWT access and refresh tokens. I want to return custom claim in the token here.

The view:

```
class CreateUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CreateUserSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create a custom function to get new refresh and access tokens with adding some extra info (your custom claim):

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    refresh['user_name'] = user.username
    refresh['first_name'] = user.first_name
    refresh['last_name'] = user.last_name
    refresh['full_name'] = user.get_full_name()
    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    }
```

and then you can use this function wherever you want.

---

and also for CBV (TokenObtainPairView) if you like , you can use a custom Serializer as the following to get the same result :

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        token['user_name'] = user.username
        token['first_name'] = user.first_name
        token['last_name'] = user.last_name
        token['full_name'] = user.get_full_name()
        return token

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

and the url path will be as the following in urls.py

```
path('token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
```

this is just example , and change it based on your case/requirements .

i hope this helpful for you .

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to made this change in the existing `get_tokens()` function of my serializer:

```
def get_tokens(self, user):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        refresh['email'] = user.email

        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token),
        }
```

Here `email` is my added claim.